# Quick Assistance involving char's and if statements

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is REALLY trivial, I'm just sick at being stuck at step one and need to continue and I have no help anywhere else. I can not for the life of me get this function to cooperate with me. Here's the source:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void ReadDials(){
 };

void ToDigit(char *x){
    if (*x = 'a'){*x = '54';}
    else if (*x = 'A'){*x = 2;}
    else if (*x = 'b'){*x = 3;}
    else(*x = 4);
};

int main()
{
    char one;
    char two;
    char three;

    cin >> one; 
    ToDigit(&one);

    cout << "one is: " << one <<  endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

What I've tried: alternating between the actual number 2 and the ascii pointer of 2 which I believe is '32' I've used `==` to try, I've done everything I can possibly think of and I know I'm over thinking it. The point is to have that function convert user input into numbers for a phone dialer.

Problems ranging from numbers not syncing with if statements, and seeing a ':D' face on the console. It's making me very annoyed.

If I need to make myself more clear, I'll be more than happy too.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You really should start from the problem definition rather than giving some cryptic and incomplete code that is not working well, since there is no way to know what it should do (well, maybe some good guess can do).

Comment: i just need to figure out why chars arent working well. Just read the ToDigit function up top and it should be self explanatory.

Comment: In `if (*x = 'a')`, the `=` is an assignment.  You want `==` for comparison.

Comment: When I do that. It acts like the ToDigit function isn't there and just mimics what I put in. Could I have passed in the reference wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do.  That is, "I am trying to write a function that takes a char as input.  As output, it should..."

Answer (score 2):

In `if (*x = 'a')`, the `=` is an assignment. You want `==` for comparison.  Also, '54' isn't a character value.

```
void ToDigit(char *x){
    if (*x == 'a') { *x = '54'; }  /* what is this supposed to do? */
    else if (*x == 'A') {*x = 2; }
    else if (*x == 'b') {*x = 3; }
    else { *x = 4 };
};
```

It looks like you are trying to use `x` as an input and output.  Let's step back a minute.  Let's instead write a function that takes a single `char` and *returns* an integer.  This would be the canonical way of taking a `char` and getting a number from it.

```
int ToDigit(char x){
    if (x == 'a') { return 54; }
    if (x == 'A') { return 2; }
    if (x == 'b') { return 3; }
      return 4 ;
};
```

To use this form of the function, you'd assign the return value to a variable of type `int` in this case.

```
char my_input;
int mapped_number;
std::cin >> my_input;
mapped_number = ToDigit(my_input);
std::cout << my_input << " maps to " << mapped_number << ".\n";
```

Comment: THATS IT. Thank you. I didn't see anything like that in my materials. Thank you very much.